# SOAP for a newbie using PHP

Tags: php, soap

There is a SOAP web service I need to connect to but I am having a hard time wrapping my head around how SOAP works. I just recently learned the basics of using REST, which was pretty easy, and I am also taking my first steps in programming (PHP).

According to the documentation the first thing I need to do is write this header.

```
<soap:Header>

<wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1">

<wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="SecurityToken-24ada6f8-4626-4269-b786-a22361bfde78">

<wsse:Username>ws.test</wsse:Username>

<wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">test</wsse:Password>

</wsse:UsernameToken>

</wsse:Security>

</soap:Header>
```

I tried to search for a way to do this with php and I might be able to do something similar but I don't understand what I am doing though.

The documentation tells me to use WSE 2.0, but I read online that WSE is obsolete. Should I then not use that? And to be honest, I don't even know what WSE is. Is that something I should be downloading or is that something that is on the server?

If anyone can shed any light on this or suggest simple up to date instructions for a SOAP beginner, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wsdltophp.com was my solution. It's great for someone who just needs a quick fix, but perhaps not the best if you really want to learn how to use SOAP.